# Injecting resolve into resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, resolve

I was wondering, if i can inject a resolve parameter into another resolve parameter. Code would tell you more:

```
.state('videos.videosLection', {
        url : '/:lection',
        templateUrl : '/partials/videosLection.html',
        controller : 'VideosLectionCtrl',
        menuItem : 'Videos',
        resolve : {
                selectedLection : function ($stateParams, lections) {
                        ...
                },
                sections : function(Section, selectedLection) {
                        ...
                }                   
         }
})
```

I am using angular UI-router for the routing. And I need to have the selectedLection before the sections resolve is initiated.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot

Comment: Nope. Resolve inheritance only works from parent states to child states.

Answer (score 0):

Can you turn the `selectedLection` piece into a service?  And then just do something like this:

```
resolve: {
    sections: function(Section, selectedLectionService, $stateParams, lections){
        var result = selectedLectionService($stateParams, lections);
        // do something with result here...
    }
}
```

I don't know if that does everything you need, but maybe it'll get you pointed in the right direction.  Let me know if it doesn't do the trick.

Comment: The problem is, that for some reason I can not access the $stateParams in the service, thus this solution did not worked for me.. Or I was doing something wrong :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured it out, the way to go here is to resolve only one object, which has couple of properties, which are promises in itself. Check the code out:

```
resolve : {
    data : function($stateParams, lections, Video, Section, $q) {
        // defer for the data object
        var defer = $q.defer();

        // selectedLection
        var selectedLection = null;

        // if there is lection selected
        if($stateParams.lection)
        {
            // lection is selected
            lections.forEach( function(lection)
            {
                // find the selected lection
                if(lection.addressUrl == $stateParams.lection)
                {
                    // save it
                    selectedLection = lection;
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // resolve it with everything empty
            defer.resolve({
                selectedLection : null,
                lectionVideos : [],
                sections: []
            });
            return defer.promise;
        }

        // promise to the lection videos
        var deflectionvideos = $q.defer();
        // find all the videos by the lection id
        Video.GetAllByLection(selectedLection.id, null, function(data) {
            // resolve it with the data
            deflectionvideos.resolve(data);
        }, function(error) {
            // resolve it with empty array
            deflectionvideos.resolve([]);
        });

        // promise for the sections
        var defsections = $q.defer();
        // find all the sections of selected lectino
        Section.GetAllByLection(selectedLection.id, function(data) {
            // resolve it with the data
            defsections.resolve(data);
        }, function(error) {
            // resolve it with empty array
            defsections.resolve([]);
        });

        // wait, untill all the promises for sections and lectionsvideos are resolved
        $q.all([
                deflectionvideos.promise,
                defsections.promise
            ]).then(function(data) {
                // resolve it with actual data
                defer.resolve({
                    selectedLection : selectedLection,
                    lectionVideos : data[0],
                    sections: data[1]
                });
            });

        // return promise for the data object
        return defer.promise;
    }
}
```

If you guys have other methods or better solutions, let me know :-)

Hope it helped someone